# Return a future result using single event loop with decorated coroutine

Tags: python, python-3.5, python-asyncio

I have a decorator that decorate a coroutine function and assign the value returned by the coroutine to a future instance.

```
import asyncio
import functools


def ensure_prepare(future):
    async def decorator(asyncfunc):
        @functools.wraps(asyncfunc)
        async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            future.set_result(await asyncfunc(*args, **kwargs))
            return future
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Demo:

```
>>> future = asyncio.Future()
>>> 
>>> @ensure_prepare(future)
... async def check_sanity():
...     return 9
... 
>>> loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
>>> loop.run_until_complete(check_sanity)
<function check_sanity at 0x7f935300a158>
>>> _()
<coroutine object check_sanity at 0x7f934f78a728>
>>> loop.run_until_complete(_)
<Future finished result=9>
>>> _.result()
9
```

As you can see I need to run two times the event loop in order to get the future result. Is there any way to make the event loop return the value after the first run? I don't want to *await* in my code and assign the result(function) to a name.

Comment: um... why are you defining your `decorator` as async? I'm pretty sure the first time you run `run_until_complete(chech_sanity)` it is just running the decorator to construct the wrapper.  if you remove the `async` from the `def decorator` line does it solve your problem?

Comment: That's an interesting question. You're trying to wrap a coroutine in a decorator function. A coroutine must have an await in them so I'm not sure what you mean when you say you don't want that. Could you clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Keith I am doing some IO stuff using concurrency and at some point need to await for all tasks to complete before moving to something else. To do that I use a future object as sentinel (I am not sure if it is a good idea) and defined the inner `decorator` function as coroutine, which is the culprit here. This is probably a sign that I should do such things on Friday after working hours:)

Comment: You might be interested in the [curio project](https://github.com/dabeaz/curio).

Comment: @Keith I didn't use curio because as you know *it can't interoperate with other event loops* which will break a lot of things. For example when I used curio to run part of my code using [aiohttp](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), it asked me to make Future iterable:)

Comment: Oh, yes. but then there has been discussions on separating out the protocol (in this case HTTP/2) from the async loop implementation. There is a [curio example using hyper-h2](https://github.com/python-hyper/hyper-h2/blob/master/examples/curio/curio-server.py) doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code you have made your `decorator` wrapper to be `async` which is not what you wanted, it means that any time you use your wrapper it gives back a coroutine object that will generate the wrapped function:

```
>>> future = asyncio.Future()
>>> @ensure_prepare(future)
async def chech_sanity():
    return 9

>>> check_sanity
<coroutine object ensure_prepare.<locals>.decorator at 0x10572f4c0>

>>> check_sanity.send(None) #advance coroutine
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    check_sanity.send(None) #advance coroutine
StopIteration: <function check_sanity at 0x105096a60>

               # ^ the function is the result of the coroutine
```

so just remove the `async` in the line

```
async def decorator(asyncfunc):
```

And your problem will be solved:

```
def ensure_prepare(future):
    def decorator(asyncfunc):
        @functools.wraps(asyncfunc)
        async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            future.set_result(await asyncfunc(*args, **kwargs))
            return future
        return wrapper
    return decorator


>>> future = asyncio.Future()
>>> @ensure_prepare(future)
async def check_sanity():
    return 9

>>> chech_sanity
<function check_sanity at 0x105784a60>
>>> loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
>>> loop.run_until_complete(check_sanity()) #remember to call check_sanity!
<Future finished result=9>
```